# Typecasting not working in Blade Directives

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Consider the following piece of code:-

```
Blade::directive('avatar', function ($id) {
  $int = (int)$id;
  $u = User::find($int);
  return $u['avatar'];
});
```

I am calling this from a blade file like this:-

```
@avatar(2)
```

This works fine. However for some reason when a string is passed, the directive does not typecast the id into a number.

```
@avatar('2')
```

The code above is not working.

I tried it with different variations of the string to int conversion, but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestion would be most helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by Its Not Working? How you get it ?

Comment: It prints a string of the avatar image URL. In cases where I pass in an int(2), it returns the URL. In cases where a string is passed('2'), there is no output.